# Error while running nextjs using command "npm run dev". Nextjs is not recognised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js

I'm trying to learn `NextJS`, so I made a new project with this command
`npx create-next-app@latest first-next-app`
but when I tried running the newly build app using `npm run dev` I get this error

> 'NextJS\first-next-app\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
> throw err;

I try following a tutorial video but none of them face this problem, I've reinstalled `node` and `next` as well but neither helped.